# How to declare multiple required variables on one line in Dart, Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, required

For shorter code, we can declare variables in one line. For example:

late String day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7;

But how to declare required variables in the same way?

```
required this.day1,
required this.day2,
required this.day3,
required this.day4,
required this.day5,
required this.day6,
required this.day7,
```

Comment: but why do you need to specify ``required`` at a point where you haven't even declared your variables? What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to summarize required parmeters. The Language Specification [1] requires that all are listed and fully written out.

Besides the Language Specification you can also have a look at the BNF of the language (e.g. this issue [2]  provides some links to BNFs).

[1] https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec
[2] https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/19298

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ok let's wait for changes from Dart team.